# Dealing with non required forms in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am attempting to insert variables from a form into a mySQL database using a mysqli prepared statement. The problem I have run into is that one of my variables is not required and so when i don't enter anything for it in the form I get an error. 
How do I properly deal with this variable?
would i need to use a different prepared statement or could I keep the one I have?

Comment: post your code and error.

Comment: You can keep the one you have, check if there's anything present in the said fields and either leave those fields out from the query(given that you have a default value in the table for those fields) or assign some default value in the query if those fields are empty.

Comment: fyi, `null` is a perfectly good value to use as the placeholder value in prepared queries. PHP has the keyword `null`. It does what you expect in bind variables in prepared queries. i.e. don't change the query - just use `null` in the fields that are empty and not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your prepared statements dynamically. If a field is missing, don't include it. For example suppose your form has fields `name`, `age` and `email` and a customer submits `name='Bo'`, `age=27` but no email. You could do

```
$columns=['name','email','age'];//all possible columns
$p = &$_POST; //form data, eg: ['name'=>'Bo','age'=>27] email missing
$data=[];//data that will be inserted

foreach($columns as $col){
    //add available data to $data
    if(isset($p[$col])) $data[$col]=$p[$col];
}    
$insertCols = '('. implode(',',array_keys($data)) .')';//result: "(name,age)"    

$insertVals = '('.trim(str_repeat('?,',count($data)),',').')';//result:"(?,?)"
$sql = "INSERT INTO myTable $insertCols VALUES $insertVals";
```

Now you can use `$sql` to make a prepared statement, and take parameter values from `$data`

Comment: due to there being 2 parts to the form, on 2 different pages,  some of my values are saved in the $_SESSION variable.  Should i move all to the $_SESSION array or add to the post and if post how would i do that? Would it just be a hidden field in the form?

Comment: @JoshuaGertner I just showed a simple application. You'll need to adapt it to your needs. For instance you could add vars from other sources directly to `$data` by adding another condition inside the loop: `if(isset($_SESSION[$col])) $data[$col] = $_SESSION[$col])`

Comment: thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

With @Andrew's answer, he is right. To elaborate

When posting a form, you can check if the they really exist or are they null, upon checking, you can assign different values to them as to not mess up your SQL.

If you have HTML5 validations such as required, you can remove them, but still do the first step in checking if the variable really has value.